# What is the complexity of my code that prints prime numbers within a range?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

This code prints all prime numbers between `start` and `end`, based on the user's input.

What is its complexity? Is it `O(end * sqrt(n))`?

```
/**
 * Print prime numbers between start and end inputs
 * Time-Complexity: O(end * sqrt(n))
 * Space-Complexity: O(1) only one value as input
 * @param start, end
 * @return
 */
public void printPrimeSeries(int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (findPrimeOrNot(i)) {
            System.out.println("The value " + i + " is a prime number");
        }
    }
}

public boolean findPrimeOrNot(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter start number for prime:");
    int startInput = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter end number for prime:");
    int endInput = scanner.nextInt();

    PrimeNoSeries primeNoSeries = new PrimeNoSeries();
    primeNoSeries.printPrimeSeries(startInput, endInput);
}
```

Comment: More like O((end - start)*sqrt(end)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going step by step, to be concise, let's call your start value `m`, and end as `n`:

- `printPrimeSeries` method is linearly corelated to `n - m`
- For each element within the range above, the complexity of inner loop is `sqrt(n) - 2`. Neglecting the constant it is `sqrt(n)`

So, the complexity appears to be `O((n - m) * sqrt(n))`.

Comment: If you take into account that for the element `m` the complexity of the inner-loop is `sqrt(m)`,  you get the slightly tighter result `O(n^(3/2)-m^(3/2))` after integrating from m to n.

Answer (score 0):

The overall complexity is *O(end - start) * sqrt(end))*. *FYI:* I show you an alternative estimation, which is not as tight:

In *O*-notation you are interested in the worst case, therefore we can assume that `start` is always `0`. Now we only need `end` for the analysis.

The method `printPrimeSeries` is just *O(end)*, from `0` to `end`. The method uses `findPrimeOrNot` that iterates from `2` to `Math.sqrt(n)`, which is *O(sqrt(n))*. The maximum value for `n` is the value of `end`, so we can call the complexity *O(sqrt(end))* for our purposes. Combining both is *O(end) * O(sqrt(end))*, which is just *O(end sqrt(end))*.

There are interesting details to the question, which have to do with the distribution of prime numbers. You can read about it [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128349/time-complexity-of-printing-prime-numbers-within-a-range#comment268247_128349).

Comment: The complexity is not **O(n sqrt(n))**, it is closer to **O((end - start) * sqrt(end)).**

Comment: @chqrlie I disagree and the reasoning is in my answer.

Comment: Well I disagree with your reasoning: there are 2 variables in this problem, the time complexity depends on both. If the range is small, the complexity is not **O(n.log(n))**

Comment: @chqrlie I've done some research and I have to admit that your suggested complexity is indeed the tighter upper bound. Thank you for pointing that out.